# select option in usequery() in React Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Since I'm new to React Query. One thing that got stuck with me is the `select` option in [useQuery()](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery). I'm unable to understand, how to use it properly.

If you can explain it, then it would be very helpful to me.

Also, I have other doubts in `useQuery()`, I can understand it, but don't know how to use it:

- onSettled
- notifyOnChangeProps
- queryKeyHashFn

Answer (score 5):

As per the react-query doc `select` option to select or transform parts of the query result.

Let's assume you have a list of fruits and vegetables in your database
`[banana ,grapes ,coconut ,cabbage ,apple ,celery]`

And you have a `checkbox` with the label `Show items with letter 'C'`.

There are two functions defined:

```
getList()  ==> returns the whole list
getFilteredList(list) ==> takes the whole list as an argument and returns the list of items starting with the letter 'C'
```

Here is the code:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked]= useState(false);    //to manage the status of the checkbox

const fallback=[];
const {data:list=fallback}= useQuery("list", getList,{
     select: isChecked? (list)=>getFilteredList(list) : undefined
})
```

`useQuery` runs `getList` function and receives the full list from the server. Now if the checkbox is enabled i.e `isChecked is true` then the list will be passed to `getFilteredList`. Now the given list will be filtered and contain items starting with letter'C'. This new filtered list will replace the old whole list in the `{data:list}` of useQuery.